# Genymotion is displaying white screen

Tags: android, genymotion

I have installed genymotion and open it's displaying white screen for some time after that it close

Answer (score 1):

try to increase the allocated memory of the device and make sure that the vm is running

Comment: Physical memory or virtual memory

Comment: virtual memory.